# Does PIC16f877a microcontroller follow little endian byte ordering system?

Tags: c, microcontroller, endianness, pic, xc8

I have compiled this simple code on XC8 compiler and loaded the hex file into Picsimlab - simulator board (board 4) having PIC16f877a microcontroller.

```
    unsigned int x = 1;
    char *ptr = (char *) &x;

    if (*ptr == 1)
    {

        clcd_print("little Endian", LINE1(0));
    }
    else
    {
        clcd_print("big Endian", LINE1(0));
    }
```

> output: little endian

So can we deducde that Xc8 compiler follows little endian byte ordering system to program PIC16f877a?
Does that also mean that PIC16f877a stores variables into its data memory using little endian byte ordering system?

**Can you please provide link to documentation mentioning about the byte ordering system followed by PIC16f877a and XC8 compiler?**

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the user guide of the [XC8](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002053g.pdf) compiler.
In chapter 5.4.2 you could read about the endianism of integer variables:

> *All integer values are represented in little endian format with the Least Significant Byte (LSB) at the lower address*

Little endian is the default and only used endianism for all xc compilers.

The PIC16 family is a 8 Bit controller, so the controller itself don't had to care about endianess.

Comment: Although it's true that PIC16 doesn't care about endianness, some of the registers are logically wider than 8 bits and they are arranged in little endian format, like TMR1H:TMR1L.

Comment: @Mike Your statement is  "The PIC16 family is a 8 Bit controller, so the controller itself don't had to care about endianness" How controller handles integers (2 bytes) if it does not care about endianness.

Comment: @Babajan It accesses them using two 8-bit instructions. The controller doesn't care about endianess, because it accesses 8-bits at a time. The compiler can then generate instructions that would interpret the lower address byte as having the most or least significant bits, the compiler can manipulate if the data are interpreted using which endianess.

Comment: The PIC itself is only thinking in one Byte, everything else is the job of the compiler. He put two bytes together to an `int`

Comment: @Mike suppose i want to store an int variable into EEPROM of PIC16f877a at run time. In what format (little or big endian ) should i store the variable ? Bcus as u said the controller itself don't have to care about endianness ? how will the MCU read the data from EEPROM at run time?

Comment: It's up to you. Just store MSB and LSB separate and it put together afterwards. So both (little and big endianess) will work. Just think byte by byte...

Comment: If you stored the value as an int, and read it as an int or stored it as a long and read it as a long, then it will be correct.  If you stored it as two chars and read it as an int then you will have to worry about the endianess.

Comment: Some of these comments are really misleading - endianness **matters** a lot even on 8bit environment, if you work with integers or longs (or floats), compiler stores these data in multiple bytes following either logic of big or little endianness (it's little in case of XC compiler). This is important when you serialize these bytes and send them out via UART or another interface to different computer system, so that you can deserialize them properly.